# Can I safely delete a TXT DNS record applied to www, if the same TXT record has been applied to the domain root?

Tags: dns, webflow

I am attempting to connect a custom domain, hosted with [Arsys](https://www.arsys.net/), to a Webflow website.

This involves setting two A records on the root domain and one CNAME record on the www subdomain:

```
@ A 75.2.70.75
@ A 99.83.190.102
www CNAME proxy-ssl.webflow.com
```

I have made the changes to the A records, however I'm unable to set the CNAME record - I get a "this entry is incompatible with an existing entry" error.

There is currently a TXT record set for www, and the same record set for the root.

I suspect the existing TXT record on www is causing the issue - I've read elsewhere that it's not permitted (or not recommended) to have CNAME and TXT records for the same host.

```
www  TXT  20200804142826331bzsmwq204yg372en7a5ri1sr043zxt5p61vy3gdwojd2y9u
@   TXT  20200804142826331bzsmwq204yg372en7a5ri1sr043zxt5p61vy3gdwojd2y9u
```

Given that the same TXT record exists on the domain root, **is it likely that I can safely remove the www TXT record, in order to implement the CNAME I need**?

Or, is there a way of identifying what a TXT record is used for? There are other TXT records set for MS=ms... and cisco-ci-domain-verification... which are more self-explanatory.

Comment: "to have CNAME and TXT records for the same host." it is forbidden in the DNS so you can't have this. "There is currently a TXT record set for www" you will need to find out why it is there, your DNS provider should be able to help. Other than that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Thanks for confirming the TXT record to be the cause. Apologies if this is off-topic for SO. I think what I'm really trying to understand is if TXT records applied to root domains generally 'filter' down to subdomains - but I will ask this elsewhere if not appropriate here.

Comment: 1) the problem is not the `TXT` record, as in there is nothing magical or special about `TXT` records; the problem is on the `CNAME` record: the DNS rules are, in summary, if there is a `CNAME` record on a name, no other record type can exist on that specific name, so no `TXT` record but no other records either 2) again, there is nothing magical about `TXT` records or any others, there are exceptions, but the generic rule is that a record is on a name, and then has no impact on any name "below" it.